# what i the meaning of ApplicationTestCase<Application>

Tags: java, android, class, inheritance

i have been checking code, and i found the following

```
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
public ApplicationTest() {
    super(Application.class);
}
```

}

can you please explain the meaning of `ApplicationTestCase<Application>`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 0):

It is one type of unit testing of your application. You can test your application automatically base on test cases. No need to test whole application step by step manually.

More info : https://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-basic-testing.html